# Do tatkal reservations on Indian railways require any special document?

Tags: trains, tickets, india, tatkal

I would like to know if I book a ticket through the tatkal scheme using the website irctc.com whether I need to have any special documents that will make me eligible for travelling? Usually when I do a general quota booking for AC three tier if I show my PAN card, then it is enough. But will this document suffice for tatkal booking as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tatkal tickets are exactly the same as normal tickets, except on a priority quota. You don't need any special documents to book or travel with those tickets.

(Source: My dad's general manager at Indian Railways)

With the changes in rules, you need to provide ID number of any document such as PAN Card or Driving Licence or Passport of one of the passengers in the reservation form and produce the same to the TT when he/she comes to check your ticket in the train.